# Apply proxy rules to only one usergroup

Tags: squid, usergroups

I am attempting to apply an ACL ruleset to members of a specific usergroup on a Linux box running Squid that I administer.

I have created the ruleset without much difficulty, but I am having difficulty configuring an authentication scheme that will only apply those rules to a specific subset of users on the system, while leaving the remainder of traffic untouched.

It seems that the [`auth_param`](http://www.squid-cache.org/Doc/config/auth_param/) setting is what I am looking for, but I haven't had much luck parsing the documentation.

Ideally, I would like an `auth_param` setting that sends the username to a shell script, which would check for that user's existence in the relevant group, and then return some value to determine whether or not to apply the rules to them.

The documentation seems to suggest that such a mechanism would be possible, but I haven't been able to find any relevant examples.